# How do I create a data table in code in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I have a data table as a CSV file that I use to create metrics for a dashboard.  The data table includes Metric IDs and associates these with field names.  This table--this definition of metrics--is largely static, and I'd like to include it within R code rather than, for example, importing a CSV file containing these headings.

The table looks something like this:

| Metric_ID | Metric_Name | Numerator | Denominator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB0001 | Number_of_Customers | No_of_Customers |  |
| AB0002 | Percent_New_Customers | No_of_New_Customers | No_of_Customers |

This has about 40 rows of data, and I'd like to set this table up in code so that it is created at the time the R query is run.  I'll then use it to associate metric IDs with measures I retrive through SQL queries.  Sometimes this table may change -- for example, new metrics might be added or existing metrics modified.  This would need some modificatoin in the code to incorporate these metrics.

The closet way I could find was to create a data table, along the lines described in the query below.

```
dt<-data.table(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(2,3,4),z=c(3,4,5))
dt

   x y z
1: 1 2 3
2: 2 3 4
3: 3 4 5
```

[cbind with data table and data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014597/cbind-with-data-table-and-data-frame)

This works for a table with a few rows or columns, but will be unwieldy for tables with 40+ rows.  For example, if I wanted to modify a metric 20 rows down, I'd have to go 20 rows down in each column, and then test the table to ensure I switched the metric at the right place in each column -- especially where some metrics have empty cells.  for example, I may correct the metric ID in row 20, but accidentally put the definition (a separate column) in row 19.

Is there a more straightforward way of, in essence, creating a table in code?

(I appreciate the *most* straightforward way would be to keep a CSV file accessible and use read_csv to import it into R.  However, this doesn't work so well if colleagues are running this query on their machine and have a different file path to the CSV -- it also raises the risk of them running the query with an out-of-date metrics table, as they may not have the latest version in their files).

Thanks in advance for any guidance you might have!

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two options (examples taken from respective help pages):

### data.table::fread()

```
fread("A,B
1,2
3,4
")
#>        A     B
#>    <int> <int>
#> 1:     1     2
#> 2:     3     4
```

https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/fread.html

### tibble::tribble()

```
tribble(
  ~colA, ~colB,
  "a",   1,
  "b",   2,
  "c",   3
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   colA   colB
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1
#> 2 b         2
#> 3 c         3
```

https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tribble.html

### Other options:

- If you already have the data.frame from somewhere, you can also use `dput()` to get a `structure()` code you can paste into the files you are distributing.
- use the `reprex` package https://reprex.tidyverse.org/

Comment: That is HUGELY helpful -- thank you!!!